# JAXB and Interfaces seem to confuce me

Tags: java, xml, interface, jaxb

I know there are a lot of questions around here regarding JAXB and Interfaces and I did some search here but without any luck. So if you think this is already answered go ahead and link it to me please.

Now to my problem:

I have an arraylist filled with objects that get casted to an interface class:

```
private ArrayList<IEvent> eventLog;
```

And I want to save the eventLog as XML to file and load it again from the file.

I have a single interface class that gets implemented by a lot of classes.
Because of the amount of implementing classes I have, I want to do something like mentioned [here](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html) in 3.2.1.

The problem is that I don't seem to get it, cause JAXB tells me every time I try to run the program, that it does not support interfaces.

My Interface looks like this:

```
public interface IEvent {

    public abstract void process();

}
```

And my implementations look like this:

```
public class ProjectEdited implements IEvent {

    private String newName;
    private String newDate;
    private int newNeededEmployees;
    private int sender;

    public ProjectEdited(int sender, String newName, String newDate, int newNeededEmployees) {
        this.newName = newName;
        this.newDate = newDate;
        this.newNeededEmployees = newNeededEmployees;
        this.sender = sender;
    }
@Override
    public void process() {
        // call the responsible handler
    }
```

If someone could give me a tip, what kind of annotations I need to use (and where AND WHY!) I would really appreciate it.
I am also open for alternatives for what I want to do, hope someone can help me.

Greetz Saladino

Comment: Your implementation class doesn't have `@XmlRootElement` like shown in the link you gave.

Comment: I did remove it for the post, but I did try it you can believe me. I did also try to use one of the other solutions in the link, but I have a huge amount of events and it isnt practicable to specify every implementation case in a @XmlElements annotation